# Google Earth Engine quota policy

Tags: google-earth-engine

In the GEE documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/usage) there is limited information about the quota limits. Basically all it tells us is that there are separate limits for concurrent computation vs tile requests. I am hitting the 429 Too Many Requests often for computation requests.

In order to properly throttle my requests or add a queueing system then I would need to know details about the quota policy e.g. "the quota is X concurrent computations", "there's a rate limit of Y requests within a Z minute window".

Does anyone have knowledge of the actual quota policy?

Comment: You might wan to post your question on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earth Engine's request quota limits are a fairly complex topic (I know because I work on them) and there are not currently any documented guarantees about what is available. I recommend that you implement automatic backoff that adapts to observed 429s rather than attempting to hardcode a precisely matching policy.

Also note that fetching data in lots of small pieces is not the best use of the Earth Engine API — as much as possible, you should let Earth Engine *do the computation*, reducing large data sets into just the answers you actually need. This will reduce your need to worry about QPS as opposed to concurrency, and reduce the total amount of request processing and computation startup overhead.

Comment: Hi Kevin - very useful, thank you. I will follow your suggestion about pushing more computation to EE - I expect that this will help to an extent.

If after this optimisation I still observe the problem then I may tackle your other suggestion - about implementing automatic backoff that adapts to observed 429s. However the javascript client library already does 10x retry for async requests and 5x retry for sync requests. Whilst I'm sure this is already helping a lot, I cannot change this behaviour without forking the earthengine-api. Is this what you would recommend?

Comment: @NeilMcMillan Ah, I wasn't aware of that exact behavior. Good question and I don't have an answer — I may have to pass on a "can we provide something better here?" request.